# mysql union give priority to record from one of the select queries in case of duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, union

This is my query in a real example :

```
     SELECT *
 FROM (

(SELECT Deal.DealID, Deal.TitleEn, Deal.CapNum,Deal.ImageLink,
     SUM( Buy.Quantity ) AS Quantity
 FROM Buy, Deal
 WHERE Buy.DealID = Deal.DealID
 AND Buy.IsFinalBuy =  '1'
 GROUP BY Buy.DealID
HAVING Quantity = Deal.CapNum)

union
(SELECT Deal.DealID, Deal.TitleEn, Deal.CapNum,Deal.ImageLink,NULL AS Quantity
 FROM Deal
 WHERE Deal.EndDate < CURDATE( ) 
)
  )A

  ORDER BY DealID,TitleEn,CapNum,ImageLink,Quantity ASC
```

I want to give priority to the record from the first select query in case of duplicates .

How can it be done?

Comment: What do you mean by give priority, Order by, or remove duplicates? What do you mean by duplicate, duplicate id or duplicate record?

Comment: The first query _might_ get 'priority' by default, but I'd never rely on this.  Oh, never use the implicit join syntax (`FROM b, d`); if you don't specify where something comes from it can be confusing on meaning, and you may have left of the join criteria in the second query...

Comment: @LostinAlabama: Actually it is valid in MySQL. I agee on the second query, it has 2 tables without joining them. I can't see the purpose of it.

Comment: LostinAlabama:It is fixed now.

Comment: @Conrad Frix It is showing duplicate records with only Quantity field difference. It is always showing the record from the second select query first ,but I want the opposite.

Comment: @LostinAlabama to ypercube's point read [11.15.3. GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) its goofy I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a literal value to each one and then order by it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ((SELECT deal.dealid, 
                deal.titleen, 
                deal.capnum, 
                deal.imagelink, 
                SUM(buy.quantity) AS quantity, 
                'A'               sortby 
         FROM   buy, 
                deal 
         WHERE  buy.dealid = deal.dealid 
                AND buy.isfinalbuy = '1' 
         GROUP  BY buy.dealid 
         HAVING quantity = deal.capnum) 
        UNION 
        (SELECT deal.dealid, 
                deal.titleen, 
                deal.capnum, 
                deal.imagelink, 
                NULL AS quantity, 
                'B'  sortby 
         FROM   deal 
         WHERE  deal.enddate < Curdate()))a 
ORDER  BY dealid, 
          sortby, 
          titleen, 
          capnum, 
          imagelink, 
          quantity ASC
```

Comment: Btw: there is no need to wrap each SELECT of the union in brackets